# Ubuntu cannot switch user

Tags: switch-user

I am using ubuntu15.04. I have the superuser account and another user account. I can login either account with no problem. I clicked the gear button at the top right corner. I did see the two accounts listed, but when I clicked the other account, no response, no swtiching.

OK, I tried to lock the current account and thought I could then login the other. But in the locked screen, I can only see the current account listed, but not the other account, and so I cannot switch in this way either.

The only way I can switch user is to logout or restart the computer, and then login the other account.

Anyone can help?

Comment: How did you create the other account? Are you sure it's enabled?

Comment: I think it's enabled. In fact I am typing this reply in that user account, not the superuser account.

Comment: What is your ubuntu version?

Comment: I am using 15.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. I don't know why my default display manager is gdm. Can switch between users now after changing to lightdm.